# summing 2 arrays to third array

Tags: java

i'm trying to make a program for my college task. it's about summing 2 arrays and the output into third array. but there's an error ***ArrayOutOfBoundsException*** but idk where's the error.
here's my source code

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int[] arr1 = new int[3]; 
    int[] arr2 = new int[3]; 
    int i, j, k;
    for(i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        System.out.print("Masukkan array pertama ke-" + i + ": ");
        arr1[i] = sc.nextInt();
    }

    for(j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
        System.out.print("Masukkan array kedua ke-" + j + ": ");
        arr2[j] = sc.nextInt();
    }

    for(k = 0; k < 4; k++) {
        int[] arr3 = new int[3];
        System.out.println(arr3[k] = arr1[i] + arr2[j]);
    }
```

the expected is like this

```
arr1 = {1, 2, 3, 4}  
arr2 = {1, 2, 3, 4} 
arr3 = {2, 4, 6, 8}
```

Comment: `arr3` is created on each loop iteration (which doesn't make sense) and surrounding for-loop has wrong conditional expression.

Comment: `for(k = 0; k < 4; k++)` is probably your issue. Shouldn't that be `k < 3`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for(k = 0; k < 4; k++) {
        int[] arr3 = new int[3];
        System.out.println(arr3[k] = arr1[i] + arr2[j]);
    }
```

two major mistakes here. You do `k < 4`, while you should do `k < 3`
Also, you shouldn't re-create the array each iteration. Try this:

```
int[] arr3 = new int[3];
for(k = 0; k < 3; k++) {
        arr3[k] = arr1[k] + arr2[k]; // i and j don't make sense here.
    }
```

Printing the arrays, you can do after this.

Comment: thank you, silly me for doing such a simple mistake!

Answer (score 0):

Based on your expected output, your array size should be 4 instead of 3. Your code should look like this

```
    int[] arr1 = new int[4]; 
    int[] arr2 = new int[4];
```

Your code received an ArrayOutOfBoundsException because the k in your 3rd for loop should be 3 instead of 4 since your k should be less than your array size which is 3. One thing to mention is that instead of hard-coding your array size, it is a better practice to assign a variable to store the size of the array so that you will not need to keep track of the size. Or you can just do this every time you use a for loop:

```
    k < array.length
```

Answer (score -1):

The problem is the input length is 3 and the output length is 4.

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
int[] arr1 = new int[3];
int[] arr2 = new int[3];
int i, j, k;

//Changed 3 below to 4

for(i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    System.out.print("Masukkan array pertama ke-" + i + ": ");
    arr1[i] = sc.nextInt();
}

//Changed 3 below to 4;

for(j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
    System.out.print("Masukkan array kedua ke-" + j + ": ");
    arr2[j] = sc.nextInt();
}

for(k = 0; k < 4; k++) {
    int[] arr3 = new int[3];
    System.out.println(arr3[k] = arr1[i] + arr2[j]);
}
```

Comment: this answer is plain wrong. your code would crash on arrayIndexOutOfBounds. The length of the arrays is still 3, while you are going to look for fourth elements

Comment: Using this data: arr1 = {1, 2, 3, 4}  
arr2 = {1, 2, 3, 4} 
arr3 = {2, 4, 6, 8} the length of each array is 4.

Comment: int[] arr1 = new int[3];
int[] arr2 = new int[3];